# Using nginx's try_files with behaviour on HTTP method

Tags: nginx, configuration

I've cleaned up my nginx config replacing all the `if`s with `try_files` but I've got this last one that is bugging me. I wan't it to behave like try_files only if the HTTP method is **not** `DELETE`. Delete is used to remove the cached file.

Thanks for your lights!

```
location / {
    if ($request_method ~ ^DELETE$) {
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 last;
    }
    if (-e $request_filename) {
         break;
    }
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
         rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 last;
    }
}
```

**BTW :** the more I think about this, the more it seems to be quite insecure…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I've found is to keep the first `if` but replace the two others with the better [`try_files`](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#check-if-file-exists).

```
location / {
    if ($request_method ~ ^DELETE$) {
        rewrite ^ /index.php last;
    }

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```